# Is this website really blocking HTML and is there a way around it?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Inside the following HTML class I requests won't return the HTML file that I see when inspecting the webpage. Upon inspection it also says overflow at the end of the line. Are they intentionally blocking people from scraping the website and is there a way around it?

```
<div class="LoadingOverlay_loader__iZ0Nm" data-is-fading="false" data-hidden="true" data-relative="false" style="transition-duration: 100ms;">`
```

I can add more of the html file if needed. Sorry in advance if I didn't format properly.

I tried saving the file with the following code expecting the full HTML file but the part I want is missing.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.nba.com/stats/teams/boxscores?Season=2019-20')

with open('nba_scrape_test.html','wb+') as f:
    f.write(page.content)
```

Comment: It's a dynamic website that uses JavaScript to fill in the contents.

Comment: Use `View Source` to see what `requests.get` is getting.

Comment: Use Selenium to run JavaScript on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a table from a page, then you can make a GET request to their API. Maybe headers are a bit overwhelmed, but I just copy them from my browser.

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'stats.nba.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'origin': 'https://www.nba.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.nba.com/',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not_A Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="120", "Google Chrome";v="120"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"macOS"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

params = {
    'Counter': '1000',
    'DateFrom': '',
    'DateTo': '',
    'Direction': 'DESC',
    'ISTRound': '',
    'LeagueID': '00',
    'PlayerOrTeam': 'T',
    'Season': '2019-20',
    'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
    'Sorter': 'DATE',
}

response = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguegamelog', params=params, headers=headers)
```

Comment: How did you see what headers and params to call? How did you know to use that URL?

Comment: @ChipperBaker You can find all the information about browser requests in a network tab from the dev tools. Just check [Google Chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools)